# Laravel new package not finding correct controller path

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 5.6.39 I've installed a package called [Mercurius Messenger](https://github.com/launcher-host/mercurius#installation)

This package installs all of it's assets through composer so I can view them in `/vendor/launcher/`

In their repo they have a routes file.

```
Route::group([
    'as'         => 'mercurius.',
    'namespace'  => '\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers',
    'middleware' => [
        // 'Mercurius',
        'web',
        'auth',
    ],
], function () {
    // Mercurius home
    Route::get('/messages', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
    // User Profile
    Route::get('/profile/refresh', 'ProfileController@refresh');
    Route::get('/profile/notifications', 'ProfileController@notifications');
});
```

The name space for the controllers is added above:

```
\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers
```

When I try to hit one of these routes I get this error:

```
"Class App\Http\Controllers\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers\MessagesController does not exist"
```

It's obviously adding the namespace to the current name space for my App\Http\Controllers, is there anyway to work around this? Or do I have to copy all the relative files into my project and sort out where they should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need (or want) to copy the vendor files into your project.

The simplest option is probably to remove the `namespace` attribute from your route group and use the full namespace when defining the route.

```php
Route::get('/messages', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => '\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers\MessagesController@index']);
Route::get('/profile/refresh', '\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@refresh');
Route::get('/profile/notifications', '\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@notifications');
```

Alternatively, you could create a new routes file (e.g., **mercurius.php**) and map it in your **RouteServiceProvider.php** with the correct namespace.

```php
public function map()
{
    // ... existing route groups

    $this->mapMercuriusRoutes();
}

protected function mapMercuriusRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware(['web','auth','Mercurius'])
         ->namespace('\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers')
         ->group(base_path('routes/mercurius.php'));
}
```